# Merge two columns into one and add one extra column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to merge two columns into one column and want to add one extra column to show relationship between two columns as shown below in the example.

**Example**

Here is the employee table example:

Table: Employee

```
create table employee
(
 name varchar(10),
 empid1 varchar(10),
 empid2 varchar(10)
 );
```

Inserting some records:

```
 insert into employee values('ax','A101','X101');
 insert into employee values('by','B101','Y101');
 insert into employee values('cz','C101','Z101');
 insert into employee values('dw','D101','W101');

select * from employee;

name   empid1  empid2
---------------------
 abc    A101    X101
 by     B101    Y101
 cz     C101    Z101
 dw     D101    W101
```

**Note**: Now I want to merge `empid1` and `empid2` into one and also want to add one extra column to show relationship between two columns as shown below in the expected result.

Expected Result:

```
name   IdType  IdValues
-----------------------    
abc     empid1   A101
by      empid1   B101
cz      empid1   C101
dw      empid1   D101
abc     empid2   X101
by      empid2   Y101
cz      empid2   Z101
dw      empid2   W101
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to achieve this:

```
SELECT  upvt.Name,
        upvt.IDType,
        upvt.IDValues
FROM    Employee AS e
        UNPIVOT
        (   IDValues
            FOR IDType IN ([empid1], [empid2])
        ) AS upvt
ORDER BY upvt.IDType;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ef0f/2)**

An alternative is to use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT  e.Name,
        upvt.IDType,
        upvt.IDValues
FROM    Employee AS e
        CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES
            ('empid1', e.empid1),
            ('empid2', e.empid2)
        ) AS upvt (IDType, IDValues)
ORDER BY upvt.IDType;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ef0f/3)**

`UNPIVOT` works fine for this scenario, but the `CROSS APPLY` approach is more versatile if you need to unpivot more columns, or do something slightly more complex.